# Why type any is returned?

Tags: scala

I have following ADT

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {

  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
  }

  def getOrElse[B>:A](default: => B): B = this match {
    case None => default
    case Some(a) => a
  }

}

case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

I've play a bit with the `getOrElse` function:

```
scala> Some(4).getOrElse(44)
res1: Int = 4

scala> Some(4).getOrElse("Hello")
res2: Any = 4
```

Why the last return the `Any` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said `B` must be a super type of `A`.

In the first example, both `A` and `B` are ints, so there's no problem.

In the second example, you have String and ints. The only super type of int that satisfies your constraint `[B>:A]` is `Any`.

Think about it like this: what type did you expect it would return? You have an int type defaulting to a String type. The type must be `Any` for that to be possible.

Comment: I just start learning scala, because I wondering why. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Scala's your system has a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: It is so confuse sometimes.

Comment: @zero_coding It lets you be very specific about what types you want. It's powerful, but takes a bit to wrap your head around. Keep at it.